# Hex Bitmasking in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, bitwise-operators, bin

What is the most pythonic / simplest way to achieve bit masking using hex representation of data please?

For example, I have

```
test = b'\x02\x00\x00\x01'
ref = b'\x02\x00\x00\x00'
```

And I want to effectively compute bitwise:

```
test & ref
```

It seems Python can't compare bytes type objects, so I think I need to convert to some other representation first, but I'm not which / the optimum way to do it.

binascii and struct packages look reasonable, but convert to decimal numbers. Is this correct?

Comment: Rule number 1 of dealing with arrays: always, *always* use NumPy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - what numpy function would you recommend?

Comment: Numpy arrays support `&` directly, and apply it element-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `bytes` do not support a bitwise `&` operation, integers do. So we can iterate over the byte sequences (which yields ints), apply the `&` operation, and convert them back to a byte sequence:

```
>>> bytes(map(operator.and_, b'\x02\x00\x00\x01', b'\x02\x00\x00\x00'))
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00'
```